# How to change the image on the ApplicationBar from C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, icons

I have a small C# project that has an ApplicationBar. But I have a small problem: I want 8 icons on the bar, and the ApplicationBar only supports 4. I came up with a solution (in C#): add a small CheckBox to ask if the user wants to use the first or second set of tools.

But I'm still not able to change the icons on the ApplicationBar. I tried removing the old ones, first with `ApplicationBar.MenuItems.Remove(Button1);` and then with `ApplicationBar.Buttons.Remove(Button1);`
 but neither worked. I tried changing the `.IconUri` property of the button, but that gave me a NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean by changing it from "C#, not Silverlight". C# is a programming language and Silverlight is a framework. Nevertheless, the link you posted to explains exactly how you do it. The ApplicationBar is not a Silverlight control, it's part of the native OS. You can use the code in the link or do something like this:

```
firstAppBarButton = (ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[0];
firstAppBarButton.Text = "New Text";
firstAppBarButton.IconUri = new Uri("/appbarIcon.png",UriKind.Relative);
```

You need to get the `ApplicationBarIconButton` via the index (0 for first one, 1 for second etc..) instead of by name.

Comment: I believe the confusion is between Silverlight (which is a framework) and XAML which is the XML markup used to define pages in the Silverlight framework.  The code provided in this answer still runs in the Silverlight framework, but it is in C# code, not XAML markup.

Answer (score 2):

You can't refer to the application buttons by name. Try:

```
((ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[0]).Remove
```

I would also suggest that you do not present two groups of 4 icons to the user. The limit is 4 for a reason. Any more than that requires a UI re-think. Perhaps divide the functionality over a few pages?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax above gave me a compile error.  With some additional research, I got this to work for me:

```
ApplicationBar.Buttons.Remove((ApplicationBarIconButton) ApplicationBar.Buttons[0]);
```