# Set ApplicationBarIconButton icon using Bitmap

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the image on the ApplicationBar from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181367/how-to-change-the-image-on-the-applicationbar-from-c)

Is it possible to set `ApplicationBarIconButton` icon using bitmap (or `ImageSource`)?

(Case I generate image "on fly" to make icon like an icon at "today" button in standart calendar in Windows Phone 7)

Comment: Yes, i try save bitmap to isolated storage and set `ApplicationBarIconButton` `IconUri` property to saved file (using  isostore: in path to saved image), but get errors with such type of path.

Comment: Also don't find any way to set bitmap without set `IconUri` for `ApplicationBarIconButton`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181367/how-to-change-the-image-on-the-applicationbar-from-c

Comment: Thank's, but i know how to change `ApplicationBarIconButton` using `IconUri`. Here is other problem - i have generated biitmap, which i should set as icon for `ApplicationBarIconButton` (i havn't uri adress for image, case it ggenerated "on fly" in application)